# Can a default-only image be set by Facebook OpenGraph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I know of the OpenGraph "og:image" meta tag that can be used on the site however when I specify the image on the page it shows up as the ONLY image. I have tried a few different changes and nothing has worked so far.

Is there a way to specify an image through Facebook's OpenGraph (or not) that will be used as a first image but still include the other auto-selected images after? I do not currently have the ability to dynamically pull all required images into the header of the page. Specifying an "og:image" in the header of all the pages causes ONLY that one image to appear as the image when you share any of the urls.

For instance, we have a logo that we want to use at the default (first) image when someone shares any link under domain somespecifieddomain.com. After placing the "og:image" tag in the header the other automatically selected images disappear and only the specifed imaage is available to select. This occurs for all paths as well so somespecificdomain.com/path/to/somewhere also uses that same ONE image that was specified. Can it be used as the first and still include the automatically pulled images as selectable image 2, 3, 4, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple `og:image` tags for a page. The user then gets the ability to choose which of the images display when they share a post.

See the [Open Graph Protocol Array documentation](http://opengraphprotocol.org/#array)

Comment: Thank you, I know it can be added multiple times but I can not do that on the current system (I can only specify 1 image on our system). I was looking to see if there is a way of defining what the first image will by while allowing the rest to be auto-populated by Facebook as it normally would without the og:image tag.

Comment: You can try not specifying any `og:image` tags. Sometimes Facebook will scrape your page for images if it's missing. Sometimes it won't.

Comment: That is how it was originally and it seemed to pick up on the site logo first which is what we wanted but within the past week or two the images that are presented are not favorable (the logo no longer appears as an option and ad logo images are sometimes appearing as the first image).

Comment: It would make more sense programatically if we had the ability to do something like this: `<img src="..." og:imageRank="1" alt="..." ... />` rather than trying to load up and pack certain images in the header of the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, FB is getting stricter. You'll need to rework your system to provide multiple `og:image` tags to get what you want. Otherwise, you get what Facebook wants.

Answer (score 0):

cpilko is correct.  If you specify an og:image, that is what is used.  You have to define multiple og:image tags in order for your user to choose.  If you can't do that, do not use og:image at all.  Facebook "should" eventually pull images from your page for you, but these are cached and may not update to your likening.  You can try to force Facebook to refresh those by using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.  From our experience on meltedjoystick.com, the images pulled by Facebook are not to our likening and we have to define our own.

Nick - meltedjoystick.com

Comment: Thanks Nick, I was hoping there would be an easier way but I don't see one.